# Sending data from and to sockets while using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

I am currently in the process of programming Mensch Ärgere dich nicht in Java. But I'm getting nowhere, because the server that sends the game files and the client get the wrong data (both run in one program via threads, where the data is exchanged via sockets).
I would be happy if someone could look into this.

The exact problem:
At the beginning of the program 2 threads are created: one server and one client. The client gets the game again and again (as an object) and has to make a selection when it's the client's turn and send it to the server.

The client receives the data rather unreliably, however, and sometimes not at all.
Sending it back works, though.

For example, on the server it's the turn of the red team, but the client says it's the turn of the blue team.

Console output:

```
SERVER: Currently playing: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0] is bot: false
SERVER: Team java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0] is playing
Würfel zeigt 5
SERVER: Dice rolled: 5
SERVER: Object sent
SERVER:     Broadcasted to all clients

CLIENT:     Spiel recived
SERVER:     Recived confirmation from client: true
SERVER:     Got confirmation from all CLients

CLIENT:     Confirmation sent
SERVER: Team is a Bot; Waiting for client to select stone
CLIENT:     getLastDiceRoll is not null: 1
SERVER:     Waiting for client to select stone

CLIENT:     Waiting for server...
```

I'm using java 11 on Windows. And can't use any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Java does not really copy the Object as I thought it would. I had to create a copy method of every instance that was important.

So for example, this will send the game to the Client:

```
    public void sendToClient(Game game) throws IOException, CloneNotSupportedException {
        System.out.println("SERVER:\tSending object to client");
        outputStream.writeObject(game.clone());
        outputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("SERVER:\tObject sent");
    }
```

The Game Class now needs to implement the Cloneable interface and save the things you want to save in your Game Class clone (or at least how you want to clone it):

```
    @Override
    public Game clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Game clone = (Game) super.clone();
        clone.teams = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Team team : teams) {
            clone.teams.add(team.clone());
        }
        clone.playingField = playingField.clone();
        clone.numPlayers = numPlayers;
        clone.gameIsRunning = gameIsRunning;
        clone.currentlyPlaying = currentlyPlaying.clone();
        clone.lastDiceRoll = lastDiceRoll;
        clone.firstRun = firstRun;
        clone.numBots = numBots;
        clone.difficulty = difficulty;
        return clone;
    }
```

If your Game Class is referencing other classes, they need to be cloned as well (and therefor also have to implement the Cloneable interface).

Comment: it might be useful to other readers to share some code examples about what you are talking about

Comment: I have provided some example code now